# How to check whether user is ACTIVE when retrieved from microsoft graph API

Tags: azure

Need to fetch only ACTIVE users through microsoft graph API.
 GET /users
how is it possible and how can we we verify whether returned users are active only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can find the answer in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of the API.

There's a [filter parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter) that you can pass to your request. Filter supports the property accountEnabled of the [User entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity), so you can use this property to find active user.

Here's the request you have to use:

> GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=accountEnabled+eq+true

Comment: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=accountEnabled
giving unsupported query

Comment: I updated my comment. Try to call the API with the updated call.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the [user's details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) from Graph API using id or userPrincipalName (which is an email address).

From Microsoft Graph API reference:

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}
```

Comment: is this endpoint (GET /users) always give ACTIVE users or deleted users as well ??

Comment: OP wants active users, not a specific user